# Is this an efficient way to remove a table row from a table body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm new to coding and I was wondering if there are more simple ways to traverse the DOM, get what elements I need and delete a row when clicked. If possible, I would greatly prefer these answers to be done in Vanilla JavaScript, for I am currently trying to truly understand the syntax of this language.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lets do this</h1>
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body1">
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="srow">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="row">2 </th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


   let body = document.getElementById('body1')
   let trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
   for(let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
     trs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
       body.removeChild(trs[i])
     })
   }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are doing is the simplest, only thing simpler to read perhaps would be using a `forEach` loop but would be the same essentially

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using `.remove()`, it's a bit more concise:

```js
for (const tr of document.querySelectorAll('#body1 tr')) {
  tr.addEventListener('click', () => tr.remove());
}
```

```html
<h1>Lets do this</h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body1">
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="srow">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="row">2 </th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-row="row" class="rows">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event delegation to avoid adding an event on each `tr`. For example:

```js
let body = document.getElementById('body1');

body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.parentNode.tagName = 'TR') {
    body.removeChild(evt.target.parentNode);
  }
});
```

This makes the assumption that there aren't any children inside your `td`s, which may not be the case later on. If you have children, you'll have find the parent `tr`, in which case it may not be as efficient if you have to loop.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this https://jsfiddle.net/m92ehp5k/

```
let tableRef = document.getElementById('body1');
tableRef.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.target.parentNode.remove();
;})
```